# TextSwitcher - Get the style attribute and pass it to another view

Tags: android, android-theme

I am using a TextSwitcher with a TextView factory. I would like to pass the style I set on the TextSwitcher down to the TextViews.

TextSwitcher does not have a 3 arg constructor.

Is it possible to get the style attribute from the attribute set?

Xml

```
<com.my.TextSwitcher
    style="@style/My.TextView.Style"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Java

```
public class MyTextSwitcher extends TextSwitcher {

    public MyTextSwitcher(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        int style = attrs.getAttributeIntValue("", "style", 0);    // I tried this to no avail
        setFactory(new MyTextViewFactory(context, attrs, style));
    }

    private static class MyTextViewFactory implements ViewFactory {
        private final Context context;
        private final AttributeSet attrs;
        private final int style;

        public MyTextViewFactory(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int style) {
            this.context = context;
            this.attrs = attrs;
            this.style = style;
        }

        @Override
        public View makeView() {
            return new TextView(context, attrs, style);
        }
    }
}
```

is the only answer to make my own custom attribute of int that will pass the style? I can't use the built in style tag?

Comment: `attrs.getStyleAttribute()`?

Comment: LOL how did I miss that. *shame face* Yeah put answer I'll tick. Therefore `getAttributeResourceValue(null, "style")` would also work. I was doing `intValue` grrr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the `style` attribute(and pass it to the inner views) using:

```
attrs.getStyleAttribute()
```

or its equivalent(as the docs mention):

```
getAttributeResourceValue(null, "style")
```

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is to declare the TextView's in XML, however this gives less flexibility to the amount of child TextView's I can have.

```
  <com.my.TextSwitcher
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      style="@style/My.TextView.Style"
      android:text="@string/some_text" />

    <TextView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      style="@style/My.TextView.Style"
      android:text="@string/some_other_text" />

  </com.my.TextSwitcher>
```